# How to rotate image and resize with transparent background using PHP GD

Tags: php, background, gd, transparent

Following code using for rotate an image and resize the same,

```
<?php

$src = "41611326.png";

// Get new dimensions
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($src);

$new_width = 192;
$new_height = 192;
$dstimage=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width,$new_height);

$srcimage = imagecreatefrompng($src);

$degrees = -30;

$srcimage = imagerotate($srcimage, $degrees, 0) ;

imagealphablending($dstimage, false);
imagesavealpha($dstimage, true);

imagecopyresampled($dstimage,$srcimage,0,0,0,0, $new_width,$new_height,$width,$height);

header('Content-type: image/png') ;
imagepng($dstimage) ;

?>
```

But its not getting transparent background for output image. How to keep the transparent background.

Any help please

Answer (score 1):

```
function rotate_transparent_img( $img_resource, $angle ){

    $pngTransparency = imagecolorallocatealpha( $img_resource , 0, 0, 0, 127 );
    imagefill( $img_resource , 0, 0, $pngTransparency );

    $result = imagerotate( $img_resource, $angle, $pngTransparency );
    imagealphablending( $result, true );
    imagesavealpha( $result, true );

    return $result;
}
```

**usage:**

```
$img_resource = imagecreatefrompng('transparent_img.png');
$angle = 30;

$res = rotate_transparent_img( $img_resource, $angle );
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the imagecolortransparent() function.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php)

Answer (score 0):

change :

```
$srcimage = imagerotate($srcimage, $degrees, 0) ;
```

to :

```
$srcimage = imagerotate($srcimage, $degrees, -1);
```